# Python - kilobits to megabits and rounding up/down?

Tags: python

Im trying to covert Kilobits to megabits with appropriate rounding up/down which at the moment does not seem to work.

What I want to get is, down should be 33.5 and up should be 7.0

Thanks

```
>>> print down
33491
>>> print up
6998
>>> print  round(up/1000, 1)
6.0
>>> print  round(down/1000, 1)
33.0
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP
>>> print Decimal(Decimal(up/1000).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP))
6.00
>>> print Decimal(Decimal(down/1000).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP))
33.00
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the results you obtain, I guess you use python 2.x. In that case, you should cast to float before dividing.

```
print round(float(up)/1000, 1)
33.5

print round(float(down)/1000, 1)
7.0
```

From [Python Programming Wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Operators#Division_and_Type_Conversion)

> For Python 2.x, dividing two integers or longs uses integer division,
>   also known as "floor division" (applying the floor function after
>   division. So, for example, 5 / 2 is 2. Using "/" to do division this
>   way is deprecated; if you want floor division, use "//" (available in
>   Python 2.2 and later).
>
> "/" does "true division" for floats and complex numbers; for example,
>   5.0/2.0 is 2.5.
>
> For Python 3.x, "/" does "true division" for all types.